# Improved way to convert nested JSON object's boolean values into a Map with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the following JSON object

```
{
  "donor": "Y",
  "bloodType": null,
  "eligibility": {
    "categoryEligible": false,
    "suspensionEligible": false,
    "paidFinesEligible": false,
    "pointSystemEligible": false,
    "failedDocuments": [
      {
        "type": "SOMETHING",
        "reason": "SOMETHING_ELSE"
      }
    ],
    "eligible": false,
  }
}
```

I'm using Jackson to convert it into my domain object. Here are the fields I'm using:

```
    private String donor;

    @JsonProperty("eligibility")
    private Eligibility eligibility;
```

The Eligibility class contains all these fields, I want to instead of having individual fields for all the boolean values, to **have a single Map**< String, Bolean > where String is the property name and boolean is the value.

```
    @JsonProperty("failedDocuments")
    private List<FailedDocumentsItem> failedDocuments;

    @JsonProperty("eligible")
    private boolean eligible;

    @JsonProperty("donor")
    private boolean donor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [`@JsonAnySetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) field (Jackson 2.8+) or method:

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a logical "any setter" mutator -- either using non-static two-argument method (first argument name of property, second value to set) or a field (of type `Map` or POJO) - to be used as a "fallback" handler for all otherwise unrecognized properties found from JSON content.

Example using public fields for brevity.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Root root = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), Root.class);
        System.out.println("donor = " + root.donor);
        System.out.println("flags = " + root.eligibility.flags);
        System.out.println("failedDocuments = " + root.eligibility.failedDocuments);
    }
}
class Root {
    public Boolean realId;
    public String donor;
    public Boolean bloodType;
    public Boolean selectiveServiceCandidate;
    public Eligibility eligibility;
}
class Eligibility {
    @JsonAnySetter
    public Map<String, Boolean> flags = new HashMap<>();
    public List<FailedDocument> failedDocuments;
}
class FailedDocument {
    public String type;
    public String reason;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FailedDocument[type=" + this.type + ", reason=" + this.reason + "]";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
donor = Y
flags = {paidFinesEligible=false, hasRealId=false, suspensionEligible=false, acaaEligible=false, eligibleIgnoreRenewalDate=false, eligibleDocuments=false, cardStatusEligible=false, expirationDateEligible=false, eligible=false, citizenEligible=false, pointSystemEligible=false, ageEligible=false, gravamenesEligible=false, categoryEligible=false, eligibleMedical=false}
failedDocuments = [FailedDocument[type=CERTIFICATE_CITIZENSHIP, reason=MISSING]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this amazing solution, appreciate it a lot.